# How to change object property based on function parameter C++

Tags: c++, object, struct

I have a function:

```
int bitCpy(Inst a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int range = d - c;
    b <<= (32 - d);
    b >>= (32 - range);
    a.(PROPERTY HERE) = b; // a.num1, a.num2, a.num3 ... etc
    return a;
}
```

The function simply copies bits from one section of an integer and then shifts those bits to the beginning. `Inst` is a struct containing different integer values. I want the function to set `a` (the object) equal to `b`. However, I want it to function based on a parameter that specifies the object's property to be set. The reason for this is because I want the behavior to be different depending on the property that is being set.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: make a function?

Comment: @Berto99 Maybe I didn't explain correctly? I want the property of `a` to fluctuate based on how I implement `bitCpy`. If I want to call the function for `a.num1`, I want `a` to become `a.num1` and so on... I suppose I could just turn `bitCpy` into a member function and just make one for each property, but I figured there might be a better way to do that.

Comment: I think if you'd add an example use case it would make it easier to understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **pointer-to-member**, eg:

```cpp
int bitCpy(Inst &a, int Inst::*member, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int range = d - c;
    b <<= (32 - d);
    b >>= (32 - range);
    a.*member = b; // a.num1, a.num2, a.num3 ... etc
    return a;
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```cpp
Inst i;
bitCpy(i, &Inst::num1, ...);
bitCpy(i, &Inst::num2, ...);
...
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/I0xhcy)

However, a plain `int*` pointer will also work just as well, eg:

```cpp
int bitCpy(int *field, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int range = d - c;
    b <<= (32 - d);
    b >>= (32 - range);
    *field = b;
    return a;
}
```

```cpp
Inst i;
bitCpy(&(i.num1), ...);
bitCpy(&(i.num2), ...);
...
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/8byoFN)

Or, an `int&` reference, eg:

```cpp
int bitCpy(int &field, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int range = d - c;
    b <<= (32 - d);
    b >>= (32 - range);
    field = b;
    return a;
}
```

```cpp
Inst i;
bitCpy(i.num1, ...);
bitCpy(i.num2, ...);
...
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/cGrRUV)

Comment: Pointers are amazing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just use an if?

```cpp
struct Thing {
  int one;
  int two;
};

void SetIt(Thing & t, bool select, int value)
{
  if (select) t.one = value;
  else t.two = value;
}
```

If you have multiple "properties" (the correct term is data members) which are just numbered versions (num1, num2,...) then an array makes probably sense.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry. I couldn't quite remember the term for that.